# FragmentTransaction, Frame Container, Freeing Fragments and Memory Management

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-management

I have a frame layout which i use for swapping fragments. I use navigation drawer and every menu item opens a fragment. So it is sure that in the all app cycle there will be **only 1 fragment on screen at the same time** (and thus 1 activity). Below you can find my fragment start method

```
 public void startFragment(Fragment f)
{
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f);
    transaction.commit();


}
```

So when i checked on Android Studio, everytime i replace fragment with above method, **memory usage increases**. `FragmentTransaction.remove` does not free fragments and `replace` also does not free too. So after a while if i click  every menu item and open fragments over again and again, memory usage increases a lot.

***So my question is how can i free old-replaced fragments? I want only one in memory. Or we can say; I want to destroy them***

Comment: "The fact that fragment itself is destroyed and gc'ed does not mean all resources you allocated were removed too" ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18352625/2668136)) - "This happens because Fragments that have a UI will hold references to UI components [views], and these Views hold a reference of the Activity's Context" ([2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28834362/2668136)) - "[Activity: a new context and the old one intended to be garbage collected] It can't be garbage collected now since your Fragment still has a reference to the old one ." ([3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422819/2668136))

Comment: @Fllo thanks for the explanation. So i will assign every context referenced variables to null ondestroyview in every fragment

Comment: @Fllo So i am assigning every ui elements to null and it seems it does not change much. What i changed is, Created a variable called mainView  and assigned in onCreateView inflater.inflate. Then assign this variable null in onDestroyView It seems it makes a little difference. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Until your activity dies, all the references to its fragments will
>   exist in memory. Regardless of add/remove operations that happened at
>   Fragment Manager level / backstack.

Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483600/android-fragments-on-backstack-taking-up-too-much-memory) stack overflow answer by [Martín Marconcini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684/mart%C3%ADn-marconcini).

A work around can be hiding and showing the frgaments if they exists in the back stack.
Have a look on the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806873/optimizing-memory-in-android-when-managing-fragment-transactions).